# How to use autoloading to include php files?

Tags: php, autoload

This is how I include files in the `index.php` now:

```
<?php include('class.register.php');?>

<!--additional files starts-->
<?php include('register/register-form.php');?>
<?php include('register/browse.php');?>
<?php include('register/alldone.php');?>
<?php include('search/browse.php');?>
<?php include('search/mobile-left-column.php');?>
<?php include('profile/mygloopal.php');?>
<?php include('profile/profile.php');?>
<?php include('profile/details.php');?>
<?php include('profile/posts.php');?>
<?php include('profile/create_post.php');?>
<?php include('profile/browse-search.php');?>
<?php include('profile/review.php');?>
<?php include('how.php');?>
<?php include('search/more-options.php');?>
```

I'm referring to this tutorial to study `autoload` with namespaces:

```
http://www.zainabed.com/2014/11/php-tutorials-autoload-php-classes.html
```

But it uses `classname` to define a page. For my case above, no class required to include the files. How do I go about it, please?

Comment: Are the additional files classes or just files to build the page?

Comment: @Rasclatt, they are just files for pop up boxes

Comment: As you surmised, the autoloader in that tutorial won't do you any good if they are not classes. An auto include using a scan folder is about all you could do really.

Comment: @Rasclatt is correct, **autoloading** are useful for classes, as it is used because `PHP` does not have a native way of importing classes defined in a different file like `Java` or `C#` does. May I ask why do you want those files to get auto-loaded? Do you need them for most pages that you have and needs to ease up the burden of loading them for every page that you need them to be?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear, so I will answer it as I understand it. If the files you have labelled as `<!--additional files starts-->` are not classes, or are classes but are not named whereby `spl_autoload_register()` is an option, I generally make a function or class to auto-include files for me. Here is just an example. It is indiscriminate, meaning it will load everything in the folder but you could pass a second param that is an array that tells it specifically what to load:

```
class AutoloadFiles
    {
        public  function fInclude($dir = false)
            {
                // If the directory does not exist, just skip it
                if(!is_dir($dir))
                    return $this;
                // Scan the folder you want to include files from
                $files  =   scandir($dir);
                // If there are no files, just return
                if(empty($files))
                    return false;
                // Loop through the files found
                foreach($files as $file) {
                    // Include the directory
                    $include    =   str_replace("//","/","{$dir}/{$file}");
                    // If the file is a php document, include it
                    if(is_file($include) && preg_match('/.*\.php$/',$include))
                        include_once($include);
                }
                // Return the method just so you can chain it.
                return $this;
            }
    }
```

**To use:**

```
$iEngine    =   new AutoloadFiles();
$iEngine    ->fInclude(__DIR__)
            ->fInclude(__DIR__.'/classes/')
            ->fInclude(__DIR__.'/functions/');
```